# What do the three gems on the Calamity Box from Amphibia represent?

Tags: tv, disney, amphibia

So I've heard about some rumors that the gems on the Calamity Box represent the three girls who had ended up on the frog world (Anne, Sasha, and Marcy), which are the blue, pink and green gems. Since I wanted to know about them, I wanted to ask all you guys this: What do the three gems on the Calamity Box represent?